# What is the meaning of "as per history's mandate"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "as per history's mandate"?

Comment: Where did you see this used?

Comment: It's probably the common metaphorical usage of "mandate", but without more context it's hard to provide much information. Have you tried dictionaries? Which word are you having trouble with?

Comment: having the mission or authority to behave a certain way: it's a metaphor.

Comment: I *imagine* (but don't *know*) metaphorical "history's mandate" is like [Magistra Vitae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authoritarian_socialism) - Latin for "Life's teacher", and the old adage [*Those who forget the past are condemned to repeat it.*](https://www.amjmed.com/article/S0002-9343(10)00398-0/fulltext) In which context, the "job, role, commission, mandate" of History is to make sure it reminds humanity of our past mistakes, so that hopefully we can *learn* from them. But that's only my guess; I can't find a trustworthy definition, and I don't understand why the question was closed.

Comment: ...the term [occurs many times in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22history%27s+mandate%22), so it's far from unknown.